# How to position the popper arrow automatically when there is no space in viewport horizontally and vertically?

Tags: javascript, css, popup, popover, popper.js

I am trying to display a popup with the popper arrow and where ever we move around the screen the popup and the arrow should display properly.

If there is enough width and height in viewport popper and popup works perfectly.

Failure case -
If there is no space then popper arrows not working properly and it shows a random position.

Expected Result -
If there is no vertical or horizontal space in viewport popper should automatically adjust the position and display above the selected DOM.

Popup dimension-
width - 440px ,height = 400px
popper position is set to left.

Code HTML.

```
<div class="popup id='popup>
<div id="arrow" data-popper-arrow></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.popup{
width:440px;
height:400px;
}
#arrow{
position: absolute;
width: 8px;
height: 8px;
z-index: -1;
transform: rotate(45deg);
background:white;
}


  #popup[data-popper-placement^='top'] > #arrow{
    bottom: -4px;
  }
  
  #popup[data-popper-placement^='bottom'] > #arrow{
    top: -4px;
  }
  
  #popup[data-popper-placement^='left'] > #arrow{
    right: -4px;
  }
  
  #popup[data-popper-placement^='right'] > #arrow{
    left: -4px;
  }
```

Popper code

```
createPopper(elementSel, popup, {
            placement: position,
            modifiers: [
                {
                    name: 'offset',
                    options: {
                        offset: [0, 12]
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
```